# Assert uniqueness of fields in list

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing, assert

I have made a list in C# and I want to make a test to see if all the values of the Id fields are unique.

```
public static List<RestaurantReview> _reviews = new List<RestaurantReview>
{
    new RestaurantReview
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "McDonalds",
    },
    new RestaurantReview
    {
        Id = 2,
        Name = "Burger King",
    },
}
```

Because I did some debugging I fount out that it is running trough the list but I do not get the proper test value. Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CheckReviewIds()
{
    var FirstReview = ReviewsController._reviews.First();
    bool AllUniqueIds = ReviewsController._reviews.All(s => s.Id == FirstReview.Id);

    Assert.IsFalse(AllUniqueIds);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking that all values are not equal to the first. This can be the case if the values are for example `[1, 2, 3, 3`], none are equal to the first but itself, but `3 == 3`.

Instead, you can `GroupBy` to group them by value and then check that they are distinct. I'm assuming performance isn't a big issue here (that's the case if the list is less than 100000 items which I assume):

```
 ReviewsController._reviews.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Count() == ReviewsController._reviews.Count;
```

---

Note that it might not be the best idea to test the internal state of a component, instead test the API it is exposing. Otherwise, the contract you define through your unit tests is limited by your implementation detail. This last paragraph is just on man's opinion though.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. <br/>This works like a charm<br/> <--Assert.IsTrue(ReviewsController._reviews.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Count() == ReviewsController._reviews.Count); __>

Answer (score 6):

Another solution that will have better performance in terms of time (specially if the data set that you have is large) is to use a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
bool IsAllUnique<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    HashSet<T> hash_set = new HashSet<T>();

    return values.All(x => hash_set.Add(x));
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
bool unique = IsAllUnique(ReviewsController._reviews.Select(x => x.Id));
```

This solution depends on the fact that `HashSet.Add` will return false if the value we are trying to add already exists.

One reason why this solution has better performance is that it does not have to go through the rest of the items in the list if it detects a duplicate item.

Answer (score 2):

I find that the easiest way to verify this is to count all the distinct values and compare them with the number of actual values:

```
var actual = ReviewsController._reviews.Select(r => r.Id).Distinct().Count();

var expected = ReviewsController._reviews.Count();
Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it in terms of code size. And it makes sense to use it if we know that the size of the data is small (which in most of the time the case in unit tests). However, if the size of the data is large, it might not be the best option in terms of performance.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I'm not sure I buy the performance argument at face value. Your solution is ingenious (+1), and should be fast if a duplicate is found *early*. On the other hand, most of the time you'll be running tests, it'll need to go through the entire sequence, and do an allocation for every `Add` (although I would be surprised if it doesn't happen in chunks). Additionally, since you're using `HashSet`, I'd expect it to call `x.GetHashCode()` for every `Add`. In the end, we can't know the performance profile until we've measured.

Comment: I agree. The solution I suggested will perform better only if the duplicate value is detected early, and will have similar performance if it does not. The `Distinct` method actually does the same thing as the solution I suggested. Internally is uses a `Set` class (which is internal to the .NET framework) to do exactly as the solution I provided. The only difference is that `Distinct` does not stop when it reaches a duplicate because it needs to get all the distinct values. I did some measurements, and as expected, the closer the duplicate is to the start, the better is the performance.