# Assert that all items in a collection have the value for one of the items property using NUnit

Tags: c#, collections, lambda, nunit, assert

I have to convert MS unit tests to NUnit and came across this assertion.

```
Assert.AreEqual(collection.Select(item => item.location.id).Distinct().Count(), 1);
```

I was hoping the there would be an elegant way to write that with constraints but I have not been able to find one. My solution is this, but Im not that happy with it:

```
Expect(collection.Select(item => item.location.id).Distinct().Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
```

Is there a better way of writing that assertion where the intent is clearer readable? (Using `Has.` or `Map(collection).` )

---

**Edit 2:**

I just realized it may be helpful to clearly state what the intent is:

all items in the collection have the same location ID (without knowing what that ID is)

---

**Edit 1:**

This is what the collection may look like as JSON:

```
[{itemId=1, location={name="A", id=1}},
 {itemId=2, location={name="A", id=1}},
 {itemId=3, location={name="A", id=1}}]
```

distinct.count = 1     => pass

```
[{itemId=1, location={name="A", id=1}},
 {itemId=2, location={name="A", id=1}},
 {itemId=4, location={name="B", id=2}}]
```

distinct.count = 2     => fail

**Edit 3: my final solution, based on Fabio's answer**

```
IEnumerable<long?> locationIds = collection.Select(item => item.location.id);
Expect(locationIds, Has.All.EqualTo(locationIds.FirstOrDefault()));
```

Comment: You are expecting all items to be unique? Can you post an example of what the collection may look like?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the value of this assert, calling .Distinct will automatically strip away all duplicates for you, and your result will always be equal to 1.

Comment: @MoeGhafari good spot. In fact the only way that will fail is if the list is empty as the condition will always hold true.

Comment: @MoeGhafari I just added what the collection may look like; this is to assure that all items are in the same location

Comment: @DrSchizo In my understanding `Select(item => item.location.id)` projects the location IDs of each item as a new list, `Distinct()` will kick all duplicates and count will then return the number of unique location IDs in the collection

Comment: @Holly however as mentioned earlier there is no value in this test. You have a list and filtering the list within your test. You are not testing any business logic here. You are testing .NET that the distinct operation works as it should.

Comment: @Holly Can you try something like this?

    foreach(var elm in collection)
    {
        Assert.That(collection, Has.None.Matches(x => x.location.name.equals(elm.location.name) && !x.location.id.equals(elm.location.id))))
    }
So iterating over the list and making sure that there arent any other elements with the same location and diffirent ID might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Readable version

```
int expectedCount = 1;
int actualCount = collection.Select(item => item.location.id)
                            .Distinct()
                            .Count()

Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);
```

I am not sure but you can try this version, where phrase "*Is all equal to...*" must help to "non-programmers" and your code get rid of "magic" numbers

```
var value = collection.Select(item => item.location.id).FirstOrDefault();
Assert.That(collection.Select(item => item.location.id), Is.All.EqualTo(value));
```

Comment: sorry, but to me that is not any better; I was hoping to use the NUnit constraints API not just reformat that lambda epression, I would like something that a none-programmer can read and understand

Comment: Seems as though the above is the simplest. See answer from Mark Seeman http://stackoverflow.com/a/32936435/1134076

Comment: @Holly, `Is.All.EqualTo` is another way to assert that collection contains items with same `location.id`. There are `Has.Exact` constraint can be used for the count of distinct values

Comment: @Fabio well those two were my first guesses and this is kinda what I want; the problem is, I do not know the value the location ID needs to be equal to, only that all location IDs have to be the same

Comment: @Holly, as shown in my answer you can retrieve first value from the collection, then compare it to other values in the collection

Comment: @Fabio I guess your second answer is about as close as I can get, although I dislike doing the same projection twice, so I changed it a bit - see my 3rd Edit - thanks

Answer (score 8):

If I've understood what you want to do... this should do it...

```
Assert.That(collection.Select(() => item.location.id), Is.Unique);
```

**Leaving this wrong answer here... somebody may want to test uniqueness, but that's not what this guy wanted!!!**

Comment: Oh wait! I hadn't understood. You want the opposite of unique. :-)

Comment: It's actually a gap in the fluent syntax, although it's not something anyone has asked for over the years so may not be a big deal. Feel free to request a feature.

Comment: I also need this feature.
Is 'Is.All.Not.Unique' wrong?

Comment: This is what I was looking for today ;)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the data in your example, noting that `name` is equal where `Id` is equal, you could use:

```
var distinctLocations = collection.select(item => item.location).Distinct();

Assert.That(distinctLocations, Has.Exactly(1).Items);
```

If that assumption is incorrect, you would of course need to extract just the `id`.